# Problem with createActionThunk redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Hello I made a `createAsyncThunk` function which is manipulating the actual state (it removes value with specific index). It executes but it doesn't update the firebase database and I'm not getting the value of `categories` array in the `extraReducers`. I don't know why because when I use console.log the `categories` array has got values. I'm using typescript and redux toolkit.

```
export const removeCategory = createAsyncThunk(
"categories/removeCategory",
async (index: number, thunkAPI) => {
    const state = thunkAPI.getState() as RootState;
    const categories = [...state.categories];
    categories.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(categories);

    const updates = { categories: [] as string[] };
    updates["categories"] = [...categories];
    update(ref(database), categories);
    return categories;
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of the code, are you sure you don't want to send the updates object instead of the categories?

```js
const updates = { categories: [] as string[] };
updates["categories"] = [...categories];
update(ref(database), updates);
return categories;
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for solving my problem